# How to get the list of all "Change Sets" of a user in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I just want to get the list of all change sets of a user in TFS. I want only the id of the change set, and a link to all items which are being checked in as part of that change set.

How can I do that?

Comment: You would like to retrieve this programmatically via the TFS-api or from VS?

Comment: @pantelif how would you do this via the api?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Besides option presented by Richard, you can also do that from within VS using the "Changesets" option:
[image]

It's also possible to do it via the API. I can provide a short snippet, if you're interested.

Comment: What is this icon(option) called? I am having VS 2010 Professional and I can't see this icon. Could you please tell me how to navigate to this option from Menu? I can't see it in View > ... either.

Comment: @RealRed Late reply, but it's called Changesets, and **you have to have the Source Control Explorer open to see it**.

Comment: This helps to find them, but the the new window's functionality is different than what you can do in the main source control explorer. IE you can't request a code review for a change set, which is the reason I wanted to find all my changesets in the first place.

Answer (score 18):

For Visual Studio 2013

1. Open Source Control Explorer
2. Right click on the repository you want to search
3. Select Find => Find Changesets
4. The "Find Changesets" window will open where you can filter by username.

[image: TFS repository context menu]

Comment: Same in VS 2015

Comment: Additionally, if you have OneNote, you can use snipping tool to paste a screenshot of only the comments there.  Then you can right-click the picture and Copy Text from Picture.

Comment: same in vs 2017

Comment: Same in VS 2019. Also, @NathanX thanks for the tip, since you can't usefully 'select all' and copy results, I will try your suggestion!

Answer (score 12):

`tf hist ‹item› /user:name` will filter the history by user, so this could be used to get a complete set of changes for a user, from which the changeset numbers can be extracted.

Comment: You mean there is no simple way of creating a query using TFS GUI?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I didn't even try: the GUI has extremely limited querying options for change history – but I see this is one thing it can do :-).

Comment: If you're not looking for a specific item, pass the `/recursive' option

Comment: You can also write it to a .txt file.  Much more useful than GUI only stuff.             tf.exe history /user:johnsmith MyBranch /server:http://mytfsserver.com:8080/tfs/myProject /recursive /noprompt > c:\johnsmithhistory.txt

Answer (score 0):

I found a round about way.

You can open a TFS task, and link a Changeset to the task. There you can browse for a changeset using search parameters.

I don't know why this is the only place where this functionality is available, but at least it's there.