# In TFS, How can I get a list of Work Items linked to any of the changesets in a list?

Tags: tfs, tfs-query

I am using TFS and I am trying to get a list of bugs that are linked to any of the change sets in a list.

My team wont to get some metrics and the only way that we can track the list of bugs that we have worked on is related to the changesets made by any of our developers.

I can get the list of change sets with VS ([How to get the list of all "Change Sets" of a user in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593795/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-change-sets-of-a-user-in-tfs)) but I don't know how to search the bugs linked to any of those change sets.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Rest API** to handle this, [**Changesets - Get Changeset Work Items**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/get%20changeset%20work%20items?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/tfvc/changesets/{id}/workItems?api-version=5.0
```

It retrieves the work items associated with a particular changeset.

---

You also could do this from UI in work item, refer from *Shayki Abramczyk's* reply in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419177/given-a-tfs-changeset-how-can-i-find-what-work-items-it-is-linked-to).

> In "Team Explorer" click on "Source Control Explorer":
>
> [image]
>
> Click on this icon:
>
> [image]
>
> Put the Changeset number or search it:
>
> [image]
>
> Click on "Details..." (or double-click on the changeset):
>
> [image]